# What is it that this #divmod method is doing to output this result?

Tags: ruby, methods, divmod

I have two arrays:

```
a = [7, 1, 65, 4, 13, 97]
b = []
```

and I'm trying to append the #divmod return values of each of `a`'s elements into `b`, via the following code:

```
b << a.map(&4.method(:divmod))
```

I was expecting the results to be:

```
b = [[1, 3], [0, 1], [16, 1], [1, 0], [3, 1], [24, 1]]
```

But instead I get:

```
b = [[[0, 4], [4, 0], [0, 4], [1, 0], [0, 4], [0, 4]]]
```

And I don't understand why. Can anyone explain what I'm not understanding?

(I'm having to use `&:` because I need to use this code as a method block argument.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with the result you are getting:

1. the array you get has an extra layer of nesting
2. the (inner) values are not as expected

To fix (1) you have to *assign* the result from `map` instead of *appending* the result, i.e.

```
b = a.map(...)
```

Regarding (2), your code is equivalent to:

```
a.map { |n| 4.divmod(n) }
#=> [[0, 4], [4, 0], [0, 4], [1, 0], [0, 4], [0, 4]]
```

whereas you want: (note that `n` and `4` are swapped now)

```
a.map { |n| n.divmod(4) }
#=> [[1, 3], [0, 1], [16, 1], [1, 0], [3, 1], [24, 1]]
```

> I'm having to use `&:` because I need to use this code as a method argument

I'm not sure what you mean by that, but if you don't want to have an explicit block argument, you can pass a proc or lambda with `&` instead:

```
divmod4 = ->(n) { n.divmod(4) }

b = a.map(&divmod4)
#=> [[1, 3], [0, 1], [16, 1], [1, 0], [3, 1], [24, 1]]
```

However, since `&divmod4` will [convert the proc to a block argument](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Proc+to+Block+Conversion), the above is equivalent to calling `a.map { |n| n.divmod(4) }` directly. You would only need this approach if you want to re-use that proc, e.g. for passing it to different methods.

Comment: Thanks @stefan for your clear and helpful explanation. FYI what I meant to say at the end of my post, now updated accordingly, was that I'm trying to pass this code in as a block argument to another method. To be specific what I'm trying to do is pass this `a.map { |n| n.divmod(4)}` into a binary tree traversal method that I've written which accepts an optional block argument. So this is why I'm trying to use the `&:` strategy to pass in (the #divmod) method, but that method requires an argument, thus the `&4.method(:divmod)` syntax, except that I want to swap the receiver and the 4.

Comment: @jbk using `&` to convert a proc or method to a block argument or using the block syntax (`{ .. }` or `do ... end`) directly isn't any different. Both pass a block argument to the method. You can use one or the other.

Comment: Thanks @stefan, I'm realising that now. I was just trying to get around the error `(&:method(arg))` gives as it seems that it doesn't allow the passed in method arg to take in its own arg. Courtesy of your help I now create a lambda; `divmod4 = ->(n) { n.divmod(4) }` and pass it in like so `tree.level_order(&divmod4)` which works well , though I realise that don't need to reuse the code, so I could just pass an explicit block anyway . A good exercise though for learning about Procs, method arguments etc. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @jbk BTW (since you said `&:` twice): note that `&:method` is *not* `&:` + `method`. It’s `&` + `:method` with the latter being a plain symbol. (and you can’t of course pass arguments to symbols)

Comment: Of course, that makes sense now @stefan. I think I now see that the `&` syntax just prompts the immediately following `:symbol` to receive the Symbol#to_proc method(?).